# Power BIを利用して、グラフをカテゴリ別表示をしたい

Tags: powerbi

お世話になります。
PowerBIを利用して、可視化ダッシュボードの製作を試みていますが、下記のことが出来ません。

■読込むデータは下記の様なExcelデータ
A   B   C   D
1   0.2 0.5 0.8 0.1
2   1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5
3   2.3 2.1 0.5 2.8
4   5.1 4.0 3.8 2.6
5   4.8 3.8 2.1 2.7

上記と同型のデータが５つほどあります。
PowerBIを使って、X軸が12345、Y軸にA列の数値として折れ線グラフを作ります。

PowerBIでは、５つのデータのA列数値について、B列数値について、C列数値について・・とそれぞれの列に対応した折れ線グラフを作りたいと考えます。

ここで、では折れ線グラフを対象数値ごとに作れば・・という考えもありますが、
できれば、折れ線グラフ一つでスライサーなどを用いて、５つのデータの「A列のデータ」「B列のデータ」・・という風に表示できればいいなと考えています。

フィルタやグルーピング機能など、なにか方策がございましたら、ご教示ください。

なお、リレーションシップに５つのデータの12345（一列目の値）を連結させています。

以上、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 今どこまで出来ていて、最終的に作成したいグラフはどんなものでしょうか？イメージがあると伝わりやすいかと思います。それから「なお、リレーションシップに５つのデータの12345（一列目の値）を連結させています。」はグラフ作成に係わることでしょうか？

Comment: 細かいかもしれませんが「X軸が12345、Y列にA列の数値として折れ線グラフを作ります。」の「Y列」とはY軸のことでしょうか？

Comment: データのX列とY列の内容を入れ換えて入力して折れ線グラフを作成すれば上手くいきませんか？(上の例だと1のグラフに対してABCDEに値を入力する。)